# Onepage checkout order successful page is blank no errors Magento 2.2.6

Tags: magento2, php, checkout, orders, onepage-checkout

I have problem with one page checkout ordering page
 after placing an order and prossesing to checkout Success Page is blank...
I tryed to change magento mode from production to developer but then checkout page crashes ...
 also debugging have no errors logs too 
 i checked `success.phtml` from `/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates`
 
here is code from success.phtml

```
<?php /** @var $block \Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success */ ?>
<div class="checkout-success">
    <?php if ($block->getOrderId()):?>
        <?php if ($block->getCanViewOrder()) :?>
            <p><?= __('Your order number is: %1.', sprintf('<a href="%s" class="order-number"><strong>%s</strong></a>', $block->escapeHtml($block->getViewOrderUrl()), $block->escapeHtml($block->getOrderId()))) ?></p>
        <?php  else :?>
            <p><?= __('Your order # is: <span>%1</span>.', $block->escapeHtml($block->getOrderId())) ?></p>
        <?php endif;?>
            <p><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('We\'ll email you an order confirmation with details and tracking info.') ?></p>
    <?php endif;?>

    <?= $block->getAdditionalInfoHtml() ?>

    <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary">
            <a class="action primary continue" href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getContinueUrl() ?>"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Continue Shopping') ?></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but all seems alright i realy dont know what to do ..

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try the following step.

- php bin/magento deploy:mode:show
- php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

Clear cache and static and deploy

- sudo rm -R pub/static/*
- sudo rm -rf var/cache/ var/generation/ var/page_cache/ 
  var/view_preprocessed/
- sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Let me know your thought after doing these steps.

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: Well i tryied everything of this but no :/ still no errors on success page

Comment: Have you removed any component from checkout or made any kind of customisation on checkout ?

Comment: yeah just added eurobank payment plugin after this i removed but it was the same... so i reinstalled again .. could we talk from chat to not spamming here?

Comment: you can leave me a message at skype : samumaretiya. I'll get back to ASAP.

Comment: i added you and im waiting for your approve name - PsyCh ॐ